# Ternary operator and GET condition

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have the following code:

```
$currentPage = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    if($currentPage < 1)
    {
        $currentPage = 1;
    }
```

I want to get rid of the `if` statement and do everything in one line. How can I do this and is it even possible to do it in the ternary operator?

Comment: Consider: What you want and what's possible might be two different things.

Comment: I want it if possible. I guess I can short the if statement in one line line this: `if($currentPage < 1) $currentPage = 1;` And it still will be better than how it is in the example.

Comment: Hint: the `if ()` block implements the second usage of the [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function.

Comment: @pidari That wouldn't work "better", it would work exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$currentPage = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 1) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;`

Taken the liberty to adjust the logic a bit. 
Please take into account that this is harder to read and code is generally read more often than written.

Comment: OKay this is exactly what I was trying to do thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's not complex, just consider the logic:

- is `$_GET['page']` set and is it less than 1 then make `$currentPage` 1
- if not, make `$currentPage` equal to `$_GET['page']`

---

```
$currentPage = (isset($_GET['page'] && $_GET['page'] < 1) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like this:

```
$currentPage = max(intval($_GET['page']), 1);
```

That will screen out any garbage and make sure the page value is at least 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe php’s **null coalescing operator** may make your line more readable:

```
$currentPage = max($_GET["page"] ?? 1, 1);
```

Remember that having a single line code logic may be good but if the price is to have a code hard to understand, it’s better to hit that enter button.
You can read about the null coalescing operator [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).